# Using Logical OR without repeating the variable in the condition in java

Tags: java, boolean-logic

Is there a way of using OR in java without repeating the variable in the condition:

For example

```
if(x != 5 || x != 10 || x != 15)
```

instead use something like

```
if x not in [5,10,15]
```

Comment: There's no 'not in' construct in Java that I know of.  If you have a lot of comparisons to make, just put the possible values in a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: or a List https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: The first check will always return `true` since `x` is always different to one of the values.

Comment: You could make your own notIn() method to do this if you happen to have a lot of this sort of thing in your code however it would basically only serve for code clarity.

Comment: You can use ArrayUtils of appache-commons library.

Comment: Someone astutely noticed that your sequence is multiples of 5.  Did your example intend that?

Comment: @seand I hope not... The question is so much more interesting if we are dealing with an arbitrary set of numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is just storing elements in an array and checking for existence, no need for OR in that case.

If you want to go that route, store your elements in a `List<Integer>` and use `contains(Object o)`

```
if(!myList.contains(x))
```

Comment: Use a Set instead of a List; the Set is O(1).

Comment: @seand No it isn't. The `HashSet` is *O(1)*. `Set` is just an interface with no performance guarantees at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of *short-circuit terminal operations* in Java8 streams (See the [Stream Operations section in the Stream Package Description](http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) for details.) For example:

```
int x = 2;

// OR operator
boolean bool1 = Stream.of(5, 10, 15).anyMatch(i -> i == x);
System.out.println("Bool1: " +bool1);

// AND operator
boolean bool2 = Stream.of(5, 10, 15).allMatch(i -> i != x);
System.out.println("Bool2: " +bool2);
```

It produces the following output:

```
Bool1: false
Bool2: true
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exclude all multiply of 5, you can try this

```
if(x % 5 != 0)
```

Comment: good observation, if the OP actually intended the possible values to be this sequence.

Comment: I don't think the OP intended to list ALL integers that are multiples of 5 in his condition ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that comes with much less performance overhead than the ones using Streams or a HashMap:

Store the values you want to check against in an array and write a small function to check whether `x` is among these values

```
private static boolean isNotIn(int x, int[] values) {
    for (int i : values) {
        if (i == x) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}



if (isNotIn(x, new int[] {5, 10, 15})) {
  ...
}
```

The overhead is minimal compared to the original code and becomes negligible if you can pull out the array as a constant.
I also find that it is nicer to read than the other solutions but that is a very subjective opinion ;-)